# Limit Scope to Parent after super() Call

Tags: ruby

I have something that looks like the following:

```
class A
  def foo
    bar
  end

  def bar
    puts "A"
  end
end

class B < A
  def foo
    super
  end

  def bar
    puts "B"
  end
end
```

The desired output is to be able to call `B.new.foo #=> "A"`. Is it possible to limit scope to the parent once super is called? This feels kind of wrong to me, so perhaps this is an indicator of a bad design, but I'm curious if this would be possible regardless.

Comment: I have added answer which can clear flow in details, once have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `B` defines a new `bar` method that supplants the one defined in `A`. If you need to preserve the legacy behaviour you *must* create an alias for this purpose:

```
class A
  def foo
    original_bar
  end

  def bar
    puts "A"
  end
  alias_method :original_bar, :bar
end

class B < A
  def foo
    super
  end

  def bar
    puts "B"
  end
end
```

Using `alias_method` here preserves a "copy" of the original method that the subclass doesn't override.

You're right, though, that this is a bit messy. You may want to declare `bar` as `private` so it can't be overruled so easily.

Comment: Making `bar` private doesn't stop subclasses from overriding it.

Comment: tad, in view of @Stefan's an my answers, you may wish to change *must* to *may*. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland With dark sorcery anything is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another way to do that, which I present for educational purposes only.

```
class A
  def foo
    m = method(:bar)
    m = m.super_method until m.owner == A
    m.call
  end    
  def bar
    puts "A"
  end
end

class B < A
  def foo
    super
  end    
  def bar
    puts "B"
  end
end

class C < B
  def foo
    super
  end    
  def bar
    puts "C"
  end
end
```

```
B.new.foo
A
C.new.foo
A
A.new.foo
A
```

See [Object#method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-method) and [Method#super_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Method.html#method-i-super_method).

Comment: This requires `A` to know about its subclasses. What if there's a `class C < B` which overrides `bar`, too?

Comment: @Stefan, thanks (I think). I guess I need the qualifier that it just works for children of `A`, which is not very satisfactory. I can think of a workaround, but it's not very pretty, but I may show it anyway.

Comment: @Stefan, please see my edit. It is an interesting question.

Comment: Simpler: `m = m.super_method until m.owner == A`

Comment: @Stefan, that’s nice. The reference to owner rather than class reads better as well.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way.

You get `A`'s (unbound) instance method `bar` via:

```
um = A.instance_method(:bar)
#=> #<UnboundMethod: A#bar>
```

This method can be bound to the current receiver via:

```
bm = um.bind(self)
#=> #<Method: A#bar>
```

The bound method can then be called:

```
bm.call
# "A"
```

In your code:

```
class A
  def foo
    A.instance_method(:bar).bind(self).call
  end

  # ...
end
```